# How do i display a blob content from SQL into html page

Tags: python, html, sql

I am trying to display data from the SQL table onto the html page

My data is a MEDIUMBLOB type data

main.py

```
@app.route("/text")
def text():
    def generate():
        if 'name' in request.form:
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            name = request.form['name']
            here = cursor.execute("SELECT transcript from `movies` WHERE movie_name = %s",[name])
            with open(here) as f:
                f.read()
    return app.response_class(generate(),mimetype='text/plain')
```

view.html

```
<div class="top">
<h1>APPLES</h1>
    </div>

{% block content %}
<div class="scontainer">
    <div id="list">
        <iframe src="/text" height="400" width="600"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

I tried this but I could not get the results that I was looking for.
It just turns up blank like the image shown below
[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMCV6.png)

Comment: Your `generate` function doesn't `return` anything…

Comment: You cannot display a BLOB in an HTML page, since it's binary data and HTML pages contain only text. You'll need to decode it to characters first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the answer. Change your code as the following.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
@app.route("/text") 
def text():
    def generate():
        if 'name' in request.form:
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            name = request.form['name']
            here = cursor.execute("SELECT transcript from `movies` WHERE movie_name = %s",[name])
        with open(here) as f:
            content = f.read()
        return content
    html_content = generate()
    with app.app_contenxt():
        return render_template("view.html",mimetype='text/plain', content=html_content)
```

and your view.html:

```html
<div class="top">
<h1>APPLES</h1>
    </div>

{% block content %}
<div class="scontainer">
    <div id="list">
        <iframe src="{{content}}" height="400" width="600"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the content of `f.read()` from your `generate()` function.

Comment: i added return f.read() but it still doesn't show anything

Comment: call the generate() function from your text() function and store its retrun in a variable (e.g., content = generate(). Then, send the content to your view. You can try another way. 
with app.app_context():
      return render_template("view.html", content=content)

Then, in view.html, use the variable content.
Also, your html file, route name and function name should be the same.

Comment: Sorry, I just started learning how to code and I am not sure what you mean